# ReferenceError: window is not defined in node js http get call

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var http = require('http');
//The url we want is: 'https://api.github.com/users?since=135'
var options = {
    host: 'https://api.github.com',
    path: '/users?since=135'
};
var req =  http.request(options);
req.end();
```

I am getting

> ReferenceError: window is not defined at `var req = http.request(options);` line.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in this code block that would cause this error. What version of node are you running? Is there more code to be shown? This runs fine for me.

Comment: did you specify port and method in the options?

Comment: try node -v to see if your node js is updated

Comment: Remove the `https://` from **host** value and then try running it.